# Need guidance to write a succinct answer

Tags: discussion, support

[What is it called when a violinist quickly bows all strings in an 'arpeggio-like' flourish?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/34262/what-is-it-called-when-a-violinist-quickly-bows-all-strings-in-an-arpeggio-like)

The OP asked for a more specific word than "arpeggio" to describe a figure.

My answer was converted to a comment, either because it was short, or because I didn't come up with a more specific term.

My answer was "Arpeggios. Covering a full octave, if you want to say more. They are repeated; and they are slurred."

No one has come up with a more specific term yet.

The question in the title was, "What is it called when a violinist quickly bows all strings in an 'arpeggio-like' flourish?" My answer is repeated, slurred arpeggios covering a full octave.

I suppose one could also say that the arpeggio covers all four strings. Concisely: **a four-string arpeggio**. I have never heard that phrase -- I just made it up -- but it would help the other person to envision the arpeggio.

The last sentence of the post was, "What is the term for this — is there a term for this?"

To the question "Is there a term for this [other than 'arpeggio']?" my answer is **No, there is not**.

That is my answer. How may I post this without it getting converted to a comment?

My source of information is a Bachelor's in Performance (Cello) from a prestigious music school.

Comment: I think that you should have put that there is no word for it, instead of just saying the word that they had already come up with.

Comment: I don't think I can edit the original response now, can I?  Should I try posting the improved version of the answer?

Comment: You can add an answer.  Make sure it adds something more than just saying the same thing.

Comment: @JacobSwanson Well, I can say that there is no other word for it, as far as I know -- isn't that what you were suggesting?

Comment: It's already been converted to a comment.  In your original post, you could've said that there was no word you know of that would described this.  I guess if you deleted the comment, then added a bit more to your answer, it would work.

Comment: I think the problem is the question.  Assuming there is a term, reason, specific use, etc. for something is rarely a good way to approach things.  But that's a reason to downvote (if you wish) -- not a reason to provide a poor answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just answering there is no word you know of that describes it adds virtually nothing to the question is borderline spam. That and the fact that the answer was very short and it was borderline of whether it would not have just been better as an comment.

Converting it to a comment was probably the mods throwing you a bone. It could have very easily just been deleted.

Comment: One commenter wrote, "Not posting as an answer because I'm really not sure, but I don't believe there is a more specific term."  I am 99% sure, and I would like to post my answer as an answer.

Comment: Aparente - a quick caution. Take on board **all** the guidance you have been given on Parenting.SE. If you start the same behaviours you were warned about there, we will have to respond the same way. In this instance I'd have to agree with the community: your post did not qualify as an answer, so it could have been deleted or moved to a comment.

Comment: @DrMayhem, I'm asking for guidance!  That's why I posted my question on Meta!

Comment: So is the following the answer to my question?  In this case, one would advise the asker that he need not continue to look for a word that doesn't exist IN A COMMENT... and it's okay to leave the question unanswered.  Did I get that right?

Comment: Your best option if you don't have an answer is to not answer. In this case a comment could be left for guidance to the OP as that is what they are for, but as Matthew commented, a downvotes on the question is more relevant here.